# delete operation not successful in Axapta 2009

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

I have written a simple one record delete operation job in production as requested by user, in an AX instance while the other instance was stuck and open. However the record was not deleted.

```
try 
    {
    ttsbegin;
    select fotupdate tableBuffer where  tableBuffer.recid == 5457735:

    tableBuffer.delete();
    ttscommit;
    }
catch (exception::error)
{
   info("Delete operation cancelled.");
}
```

tableBuffer's `delete()`function was overridden with code after `super()` to store the deleted record in another table.

I have done the same operation earlier successfully but no where with a scenario like one today(executed in one  instance while the other instance was stuck).

Please suggest the possible reason as I find the record still persist both in sql server and AX.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably the record is locked by the other stuck instance? On another note, I'm guessing `fotupdate` is a typo? And on still another note, please don't hide exceptions with empty catches. Btw, did you debug if the program runs successfully through the `delete` method?

Comment: `forupdate` wasnt a typo I am aware that a update operation doesnt require that neither a transaction block, it was a job written by someone else and I didnot wanted to change anything in prod. I have edited the code, catch is not empty in actual code. I have executed successful delete operations last week. The other instance was stuck becoz of a batch job setup. Request your insight.

Comment: I was talking about the "t" in `fotupdate`. Anyway, I guess you should try to delete the record when no batch jobs are running and no other users are using the system.

Comment: I understand but my concern is what must have gone wrong? I will make that sure in future.

Comment: As I wrote, one possibility is that the stuck instance was blocking the record and thus prevented it from being deleted. But that is only a guess, without going back in time there is probably no way to find out the cause.

Comment: Considering the reason you mentioned could you elaborate...my intension is to avoid future instances like this..thanks again.

Comment: As I wrote, you can avoid this by making sure that your job is the only process currently running. I'm not sure how I can further elaborate, you probably want to educate yourself more about [deadlocking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177433(v=sql.105).aspx). In any case this is becoming a discussion, which is better suited for [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120203/discussion-between-piku-and-fh-inway).

Comment: I want to choose your comments as an answer for the problem i faced in my scenario. Pls help

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to prevent this from happening you can use `pessimistic` locking, where you obtain an update lock.

> `select pessimisticLock custTable 
>        where custTable.AccountNum > '1000'`

See these links for more info:

http://dev.goshoom.net/en/2011/10/pessimistic-locking/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeadaxsupport/2009/07/08/about-locking-and-blocking-in-dynamics-ax-and-how-to-prevent-it/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190073.aspx